# KendoUI mobile radio button group

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to create a AppBuilder app and got stuck with a radio button group for a form. The example in http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/forms/checkboxes.html shows listview. However since my form itself is a listview, the listview of radio buttons nested withint the form listview is not working. Is there any way that I can show the radio buttons?

Comment: Try copying your code into a jsfiddle/jsbin and posting that link so we can see your form.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the following code might help you out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="forms" data-role="view" data-title="Form Elements" data-init="initForm" data-use-native-scrolling="true">
            <form action="./index.html">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
                    <li>
                        <label>Select element
                            <select>
                                <option value="First Option">First Option</option>
                                <option value="Second Option">Second Option</option>
                                <option value="Third Option">Third Option</option>
                                <option value="Fourth Option">Fourth Option</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>DropDownList
                            <select id="dropdown">
                                <option value="First Option">First Option</option>
                                <option value="Second Option">Second Option</option>
                                <option value="Third Option">Third Option</option>
                                <option value="Fourth Option">Fourth Option</option>
                                <option value="First Option">Fifth Option</option>
                                <option value="Sixth Option">Sixth Option</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Slider
                            <input id="slider" type="range" max="100" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Type text
                            <input type="text" value="Text" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Type password
                            <input type="password" value="password" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Type search
                            <input type="search" value="search" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Type url
                            <input type="url" value="http://www.telerik.com" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Type email
                            <input type="email" value="kendoui@telerik.com" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Type number
                            <input type="number" value="20" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Type tel
                            <input type="tel" value="+44 22 11 10" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Type date
                            <input type="date" value="2012-03-22" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Type time
                            <input type="time" value="22:30" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Type month
                            <input type="month" value="2012-01" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Type datetime-local
                            <input type="datetime-local" value="2012-03-22T20:15" />
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            Textarea
                            <textarea style="resize: none">Multiline
                            Text</textarea>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li data-layout="checklayout">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
                                    Lettuce
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" />
                                    Carrots
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" />
                                    Peas
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" />
                                    Bread
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" />
                                    Unicorns
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
        function initForm() {
            var body = $(".km-pane");
            if (kendo.ui.DropDownList) {
                $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
                    // The options are needed only for the desktop demo, remove them for mobile.
                    popup: {
                        appendTo: body
                    },
                    animation: {
                        open: {
                            effects: body.hasClass("km-android") ? "fadeIn" : body.hasClass("km-ios") || body.hasClass("km-wp") ? "slideIn:up" : "slideIn:down"
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            if (kendo.ui.Slider) {
                $("#slider").kendoSlider({
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        </script>
        <script>
        var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```